# How to put a background image behind div

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to put my background behind the div that contains a jumbotron, but the div keeps on staying below the background image, instead of appearing on it. How do I fix this?

P.S : I do not want to put the background image in my CSS file for some reasons, so i want the image src to only be in my HTML. Many thanks!

Here is my code :

```
        <div class="container-fluid" >
         <img src='U_Thant_PIC_3.jpg'
            width='1400px' height='800px'/>

            <div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid">
                <center>
                    <h2 class="a">Cats are cool</h2>
                </center>

            </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How about setting the z-index property on the div?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In order to achieve this you need to tell the browser to position the `img` element behind your child `div`. For the purpose you can use the `position` attribute, with the `img` having a lower `z-index`.

The `z-index` does work for this, as long as you have `position` properties on the elements:

```css
div.container-fluid{position:relative;}
div.container-fluid img{position:absolute;top:0;left:0;z-index:1}
div.container-fluid div.jumbotron{position:relative;z-index:5;color:white;}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid" >
         <img src='https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_lights.jpg'
            width='1400px' height='800px'/>

            <div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid">
                <center>
                    <h2 class="a">Cats are cool</h2>
                </center>

            </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ur absolutely right, the positioning made all the difference! Thank you so much

Comment: If my answer helped your case, could you please mark it as the "Accepted Answer"

Comment: Here the z-index isn't necessary. It only necessary when another element with position: absolute is overlapping the first element.

Comment: @JohnMejia Mate, please read some documentation, this would be a good start - https://medium.freecodecamp.org/z-index-explained-how-to-stack-elements-using-css-7c5aa0f179b3

Comment: @Darthur I understand very well the z-index, I only saying that isn't necessary here. The z-index with 5 it's a lot, and you don't need the z-index in the position relative. You should read more about it ;)

Comment: You are hilarious! "5 is a lot" ... the MAXIMUM of a z-index value is 2147483647, compare that to 5. And yes, it is necessary, it is necessary when you want to stack items. Idk what kind of modern hippy millennial browsers you are used to coding for, but as per the W3C standards, z-index is the property to use when you stack elements. I have work to do, go argue with the W3C standards, maybe you'll learn something.

Comment: @Darthur Hahaha you don't get it men, the properties are used when they are needed. Here I'll give you an example without z-index https://jsfiddle.net/mnL8cvf2/2/

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

HTML

```
 <div class="container-fluid">
  <img src="U_Thant_PIC_3.jpg" alt="Snow" width='1400px' height='800px'>
  <div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid">
      <h2 class="a">Cats are cool
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.jumbotron {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
}
```

It will give you centered text on top of your image.

Comment: I want the jumbotron on top of the background yes, but the z-index isnt solving this issue

Comment: I edited my answer, I think this is what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Add `position: absolute;` into the `class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid"`, and move your `<img src='U_Thant_PIC_3.jpg' width='1400px' height='800px'/>` to the bottom of code.

```css
.box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.jumbotron {
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="jumbotron">
    textbox
  </div>
  <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_lights.jpg">
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You need set up first the parent element with position: relative; in this case you should add the css below.

```
.container-fluid { position:relative }
```

and then you need to set up the jumbotron with the next style.

```
.jumbotron { position: absolute }
```

with this should be work, also you can move the .jumbotron with the top, bottom, left and right positions, for example:

```
.jumbotron { position: absolute; top: 20px; left: 10px; }
```

In this way .jumbotron will move in the area with the first position: relative; taken. In this case in the area of .container-fluid class.

```
<div class="container-fluid" >
    <img src='https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_lights.jpg'
            width='1400px' height='800px'/>

    <div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid">
      <center>
         <h2 class="a">Cats are cool</h2>
      </center>

   </div>
</div>
```

Here I give you and example: 
https://jsfiddle.net/mnL8cvf2/2/

Hope this can help you.

Comment: The z-index isn't necessary in the first instance, it's only necessary if the parent element have several child elements with position absolute or if there's another element overlapping the actual element. And on the other hand I given you a simple solution to a simple problem he has.